# Replace Method not working?

Tags: vb.net

I have a set of strings that all have the same pattern: "Jones, Bob - NO TIME" where it is the last name, comma, first name, then a hyphen and no time.  I want to strip the last name and first name and save them to variables.  I tried:

```
dim emp_name as string = "Jones, Bob - NO TIME"
emp_name = Replace(emp_name, "- NO TIME", "")
dim _Name as string() = emp_name.Split(",")
Dim first_Name as string = Name(0)
Dim last_Name as string = Name(1)
```

For some reason replace doesn't get rid of the "- No Time" and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Why you don't use the `.NET` method `String.Replace` but the old VB function `Replace`?

This will work for sure:

    `emp_name = emp_name.Replace("- NO TIME", "")`

Comment: Does you code even compile? Can you share the code of `Replace` method?

Comment: Your code sample works just fine for me. aside from the fact that your last two lines should probably use _Name and not Name. What is your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

It is `_Name` not `Name`, i guess `Name` is a different property of your class.

Why you don't use the `.NET` method [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) but the old VB function [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx)?

But since you want to remove the token at the end, you dont want to replace every occurence:

```
Dim empName as string = "Jones, Bob - NO TIME"
Dim index = empName.LastIndexOf("- NO TIME")
empName = If(index = -1, empName, empName.Remove(index))
Dim tokens = empName.Split(","c)
Dim lastName as string = tokens(0).Trim()
Dim firstName as string = tokens.Last().Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this two lines:

```
Dim first_Name as string = Name(0)
Dim last_Name as string = Name(1)
```

with

```
Dim first_Name as string = _Name(0)
Dim last_Name as string = _Name(1)
```

Because your array is `_Name` not `Name`